# Java Inheritance concept with ambiguous parameter

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

```java
public class A {
    public void method(Object val){
        System.out.println("Class A's method method() called....");
    }
}

public class B extends A {  
    public void method(String val){
        System.out.println("Class B's method method() called....");
    }   
}

public class C extends B {
    public void method(Integer val){
        System.out.println("Class C's method method() called....");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new C();
        a.method(null);
    }   
}
```

Why does it called A's method ? Want to understand inheritance

Comment: Do you understand that you're not *overriding* any methods in this case? Instead, you're *overloading*. I ask because it's not clear whether your question is really about inheritance and overriding, or overload resolution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ambiguity here.

The compile time type of `a` is class `A`.

Class `A` has only one method named `method` - `public void method(Object val)` - and that's the only method signature that can be chosen by the compiler when it encounters a variable of type `A`.

If the compile time type of `a` was `C`, the compiler would have considered all three `method()` methods, and this time it would have complained about ambiguity (since it would have no preference between `public void method(String val)` and `public void method(Integer val)`).

Answer (score 0):

your methods in `class B` and `class C` are not part of inheritance , because there is no `@Override` . if you want to override `method` in `class B` you cannot change parameter type.
to get your expected result try this.

```
 class C extends B {
    @Override
    public void method(Object val) {
        System.out.println("Class C's method method() called....");
    }
}
```

and you need to read differences of `overloading` and `overriding` 
`overloading` is not part of inheritance. 
in your case you have overloaded parents method with different parameter.